# Getting error Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am installing Sitecore 9 on my laptop running Windows 10, SQL Express 2016. At the very last steps of installation (around step 29) I am getting stuck at same spot.

The output is

```
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- CreateCores [11] : ManageSolrCore -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[CreateCores [11]]:[SolrCore] Performing Create on https://localhost:8983/solr


responseHeader         core
--------------         ----
@{status=0; QTime=391} sitecore9_fxm_web_index


[TIME] 00:00:29
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\sitecore\install\sitecore-solr.180609.log
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\Public\ConfigFunctions\Invoke-ReadJsonConfigFunction.ps1:13 char:74
+ ... th).Where({ $_ -notmatch '^\s*\/\/'}) | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

GetSection : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:26 char:73
+ ...  if ($params = GetSection -Section 'Parameters' -InputObject $json) {
+                                                                  ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [GetSection], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,GetSection

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SqlServer'.
At C:\sitecore\install\installation.ps1:88 char:31
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-SitecoreConfiguration], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
```

It seems to be complaining about a `.` in JSON file.

Also it seems to be complaining that `Install-SitecoreConfiguration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SqlServer'.`

`At C:\sitecore\install\installation.ps1:88 char:31`

`+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams`

I am at loss there. I am just hoping this will be the last hurdle to pass.

Closest link is this question [Sitecore installation framework fails parameter error](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9863/sitecore-installation-framework-fails-parameter-error) but he was trying to install on SQL Server 2014 and I have read at many places that people have successfully installed on SQL Express 2016 also.

Any clues on this error, thanks?

Windows 10 / Powershell 5.1 / Solr 6.2.1 / Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 / SQL Express 2016

Tested with following Ms SQL Server 2016 ending in same error

- Ms SQL Express 2016 SP1
- Ms SQL Express 2016 SP2
- Ms SQL Server 2016 Developer SP1

----------------- Installation.ps1 -----------------------

```
#define parameters 
$prefix = "sitecore9" 
$PSScriptRoot = "C:\sitecore\install\"
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix" 
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr" 
$SolrRoot = "C:\sitecore\solr-6.6.1\" 
$SolrService = "solr6" 
$SqlServer = "SQLSERVER" 
$SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
$SqlAdminPassword='Admin1234%^' 


#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
    } 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 

#install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = 
@{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams -Verbose 

#deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
    } 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams -Verbose 

#install solr cores for sitecore $solrParams = 
$solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
} 

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

#install sitecore instance 
$xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect" 
$sitecoreParams = 
@{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"  
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix  
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName         
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"    
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

----------------- sitecore-XP0.json -----------------------

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
//         Sitecore Install Framework - Sitecore XP0 Configuration            //
//                                                                            //
//  Run this configuration to install a single instance of Sitecore.          //
//  This instance is configured to use Solr.                                  //
//                                                                            //
//  NOTE: Only single line comments are accepted in configurations.           //
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
{
    "Parameters": {
        // Parameters are values that may be passed when Install-SitecoreConfiguration is called.
        // Parameters must declare a Type and may declare a DefaultValue and Description.
        // Parameters with no DefaultValue are required when Install-SitecoreConfiguration is called.
        "Package": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The path to the Web Deploy package to deploy."
        },
        "LicenseFile": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The path to the Sitecore license file.",
        },
        "SqlDbPrefix": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The prefix used for all Sql databases.",
        },
        "SolrCorePrefix": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The prefix used for all Solr cores.",
        },
        "XConnectCert": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Description": "The certificate to use for encryption. Provide the name or the thumbprint."
        },
        "SiteName": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "Sitecore",
            "Description": "The name of the site to be deployed."
        },
        "SitecoreAdminPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "b",
            "Description": "The admin password for the Sitecore instance."
        },
        "SqlAdminUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "sc9",
            "Description": "The Sql admin user account to use when installing databases."
        },
        "SqlAdminPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "admin1234%^",
            "Description": "The Sql admin password to use when installing databases."
        },
        "SqlCoreUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "coreuser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Core connection string."
        },
        "SqlCorePassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Core connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlMasterUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "masteruser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Master connection string."
        },
        "SqlMasterPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Master connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlWebUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "webuser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Web connection string."
        },
        "SqlWebPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Web connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlReportingUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "reportinguser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Reporting connection string."
        },
        "SqlReportingPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Reporting connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlProcessingPoolsUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "poolsuser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Processing Pools connection string."
        },
        "SqlProcessingPoolsPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Processing Pools connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlProcessingTasksUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "tasksuser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Processing Tasks connection string."
        },
        "SqlProcessingTasksPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Processing Tasks connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlReferenceDataUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "referencedatauser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Reference Data connection string."
        },
        "SqlReferenceDataPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Reference Data connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlMarketingAutomationUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "marketingautomationuser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Marketing Automation connection string."
        },
        "SqlMarketingAutomationPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Marketing Automation connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlFormsUser": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "formsuser",
            "Description": "The user to create and use in Experience Forms connection string."
        },
        "SqlFormsPassword": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "4rfv%TGB6yhn",
            "Description": "The Sql password for the Experience Forms connection string in Sitecore.",
            "Value": "4rfv%TGB6yhn"
        },
        "SqlServer": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "SQLEXPRESS",
            "Description": "The Sql Server where databases will be installed."
        },
        "SolrUrl": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "https://localhost:8983/solr",
            "Description": "The Solr instance to use."
        },
        "XConnectCollectionService": {
            "Type": "string",
            "DefaultValue": "https://XConnect",
            "Description": "The url for the XConnect Collection Service."
        },
        "XConnectReferenceDataService": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Reference": "XConnectCollectionService",
            "Description": "The url for the XConnect Collection Search Service."
        },
        "MarketingAutomationOperationsService": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Reference": "XConnectCollectionService",
            "Description": "The url for the XConnect Marketing Automation Service."
        },
        "MarketingAutomationReportingService": {
            "Type": "string",
            "Reference": "XConnectCollectionService",
            "Description": "The url for the XConnect Marketing Automation Reporting Service."
        }
    },
    "Variables": {
        // Database names.
        "Sql.Database.Core":                "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Core')]",
        "Sql.Database.Master":              "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Master')]",
        "Sql.Database.Web":                 "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Web')]",
        "Sql.Database.Reporting":           "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Reporting')]",
        "Sql.Database.Reference":           "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_ReferenceData')]",
        "Sql.Database.Forms":               "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_ExperienceForms')]",
        "Sql.Database.Pools":               "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Processing.Pools')]",
        "Sql.Database.Tasks":               "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_Processing.Tasks')]",
        "Sql.Database.MarketingAutomation": "[concat(parameter('SqlDbPrefix'), '_MarketingAutomation')]",

        // The security certificate details
        "Security.CertificateStore":                "Cert:\\Localmachine\\My",
        "Security.XConnect.CertificateThumbprint":  "[GetCertificateThumbprint(parameter('XConnectCert'), variable('Security.CertificateStore'))]",
        "Security.XConnect.CertificatePath":        "[joinpath(variable('Security.CertificateStore'), variable('Security.XConnect.CertificateThumbprint'))]",

        // Solr core names.
        "Solr.Core.Name":       "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_core_index')]",
        "Solr.Master.Name":     "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_master_index')]",
        "Solr.Web.Name":        "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_web_index')]",
        "Solr.MD.Master.Name":  "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_marketingdefinitions_master')]",
        "Solr.MD.Web.Name":     "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_marketingdefinitions_web')]",
        "Solr.MA.Master.Name":  "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_marketing_asset_index_master')]",
        "Solr.MA.Web.Name":     "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_marketing_asset_index_web')]",
        "Solr.Testing.Name":    "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_testing_index')]",
        "Solr.Suggested.Name":  "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_suggested_test_index')]",
        "Solr.FXM.Master.Name": "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_fxm_master_index')]",
        "Solr.FXM.Web.Name":    "[concat(parameter('SolrCorePrefix'), '_fxm_web_index')]",

        // The sites full path on disk
        "Site.PhysicalPath": "[joinpath(environment('SystemDrive'), 'inetpub', 'wwwroot', parameter('SiteName'))]",

        // The sites data folder
        "Site.DataFolder": "[joinpath(variable('Site.PhysicalPath'), 'App_Data')]"
    },
    "Tasks": {
        // Tasks are separate units of work in a configuration.
        // Each task is an action that will be completed when Install-SitecoreConfiguration is called.
        // By default, tasks are applied in the order they are declared.
        // Tasks may reference Parameters, Variables, and config functions.
        "CreatePaths": {
            // Ensure the destination path for the site exists.
            "Type": "EnsurePath",
            "Params": {
                "Exists": [ "[variable('Site.PhysicalPath')]" ]
            }
        },
        "CreateAppPool": {
            // Creates or updates the app pool.
            "Type": "AppPool",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Properties": {
                    "ProcessModel": {
                        "identityType": "ApplicationPoolIdentity"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "CreateWebsite": {
            // Creates or updates the IIS website instance.
            "Type": "Website",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "ApplicationPool": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "PhysicalPath": "[variable('Site.PhysicalPath')]"
            }
        },
        "StopWebsite": {
            // Stops the website if it is running.
            "Type": "ManageWebsite",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Action": "Stop"
            }
        },
        "StopAppPool": {
            // Stops the app pool if it is running.
            "Type": "ManageAppPool",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Action": "Stop"
            }
        },
        "CreateBindings": {
            // Configures the site bindings for the website.
            "Type": "WebBinding",
            "Params": {
                "SiteName": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Add": [ { "HostHeader": "[parameter('SiteName')]" } ],
                "Remove": [ { "Port": "80", "IPAddress": "*" } ]
            }
        },
        "CreateHostHeader": {
            // Sets a hostheader for the website.
            "Type": "HostHeader",
            "Params": {
                "HostName": "[parameter('SiteName')]"
            }
        },
        "SetPermissions": {
            // Sets permissions for the app pool user.
            "Type": "FilePermissions",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "[variable('Site.PhysicalPath')]",
                "Rights": [
                    {
                        "User": "[concat('IIS AppPool\\', parameter('SiteName'))]",
                        "FileSystemRights": "FullControl",
                        "InheritanceFlags": [ "ContainerInherit", "ObjectInherit" ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "SetCertStorePermissions": {
            // Set permissions for the services to access the client certificate.
            "Type": "FilePermissions",
            "Params": {
                "Path": "[ResolveCertificatePath(variable('Security.XConnect.CertificatePath'))]",
                "Rights": [
                    {
                        "User": "[concat('IIS AppPool\\', parameter('SiteName'))]",
                        "FileSystemRights": [ "Read" ],
                        "InheritanceFlags": [ "None" ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "InstallWDP": {
            // Syncs the web deploy package with the website.
            "Type": "WebDeploy",
            "Params": {
                "Verb": "Sync",
                "Arguments": {
                    "Source": {
                        "Package": "[resolvepath(parameter('Package'))]"
                    },
                    "Dest": "Auto",
                    "SetParam": [
                        { "Name": "Application Path", "Value": "[parameter('SiteName')]" },
                        { "Name": "Database Server Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlServer')]" },
                        { "Name": "Sitecore Admin New Password", "Value": "[parameter('SitecoreAdminPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Database Admin User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlAdminUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Database Admin User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlAdminPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Core DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.Core')]" },
                        { "Name": "Master DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.Master')]" },
                        { "Name": "Web DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.Web')]" },
                        { "Name": "Reporting DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.Reporting')]" },
                        { "Name": "XDB Reference Data DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.Reference')]" },
                        { "Name": "Experience Forms DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.Forms')]" },
                        { "Name": "Marketing Automation DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.MarketingAutomation')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Pools DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.Pools')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Tasks DB Name", "Value": "[variable('Sql.Database.Tasks')]" },
                        { "Name": "Core DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlCoreUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Core DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlCorePassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Master DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlMasterUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Master DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlMasterPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Web DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlWebUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Web DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlWebPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Reporting DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlReportingUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Reporting DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlReportingPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "XDB Reference Data DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlReferenceDataUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "XDB Reference Data DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlReferenceDataPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Experience Forms DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlFormsUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Experience Forms DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlFormsPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Marketing Automation DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlMarketingAutomationUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Marketing Automation DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlMarketingAutomationPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Pools DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlProcessingPoolsUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Pools DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlProcessingPoolsPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Tasks DB User Name", "Value": "[parameter('SqlProcessingTasksUser')]" },
                        { "Name": "Processing Tasks DB User Password", "Value": "[parameter('SqlProcessingTasksPassword')]" },
                        { "Name": "XConnect Collection", "Value": "[parameter('XConnectCollectionService')]" },
                        { "Name": "Xdb Reference Data Client", "Value": "[parameter('XConnectReferenceDataService')]" },
                        { "Name": "XDB MA Reporting Client", "Value": "[parameter('MarketingAutomationReportingService')]" },
                        { "Name": "XDB MA Ops Client", "Value": "[parameter('MarketingAutomationOperationsService')]" },
                        { "Name": "XConnect Server Certificate Validation Thumbprint", "Value": "[variable('Security.XConnect.CertificateThumbprint')]" },
                        { "Name": "SOLR Connection String", "Value": "[parameter('SolrUrl')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Core Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.Core.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Master Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.Master.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Web Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.Web.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Marketing Definitions Master Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.MD.Master.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Marketing Definitions Web Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.MD.Web.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Marketing Asset Master Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.MA.Master.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Marketing Asset Web Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.MA.Web.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Testing Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.Testing.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr Suggested Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.Suggested.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr FXM Master Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.FXM.Master.Name')]" },
                        { "Name": "Solr FXM Web Index Name", "Value": "[variable('Solr.FXM.Web.Name')]" }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "SetLicense": {
            // Copies the license file to the instance data folder.
            "Type": "Copy",
            "Params": {
                "Source": "[resolvepath(parameter('LicenseFile'))]",
                "Destination": "[variable('Site.DataFolder')]"
            }
        },
        "StartAppPool": {
            // Starts the app pool.
            "Type": "ManageAppPool",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Action": "Start"
            }
        },
        "StartWebsite": {
            // Starts the website.
            "Type": "ManageWebsite",
            "Params": {
                "Name": "[parameter('SiteName')]",
                "Action": "Start"
            }
        },
        "UpdateSolrSchema": {
            // Update the solr schemas.
            "Type": "SitecoreUrl",
            "Params": {
                "SitecoreInstanceRoot": "[concat('http://', parameter('SiteName'))]",
                "SitecoreActionPath": "sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all",
                "UserName": "admin",
                "Password": "[parameter('SitecoreAdminPassword')]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

------- QUERY TO DROP DB ------

**Please note that it does connect to SQL server and setup databases which I have to drop first to try to reinstall**. This shows my server and my settings are fine.

```
USE master;  
GO  
DROP DATABASE sitecore9_MarketingAutomation, [sitecore9_Processing.Pools], sitecore9_ReferenceData, [sitecore9_Xdb.Collection.Shard0], [sitecore9_Xdb.Collection.Shard1], [sitecore9_Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager]
GO
```

Comment: Do you have Sql 2016 initial release or update 1.

Comment: It is **SQL Express 2016 SP2** Version `13.2.5026.0`. So now I am uninstalling it and should try **SQL Express 2016 SP1**.

Comment: @VladIobagiu same error with **SQL Express 2016 SP1** version `13.1.4001.0`

Comment: Tried even `SQL Server 2016 SP 1 Developer Edition`

Comment: Can you post here your ps1 install script and also json configs if you changed them directly?

Comment: Can you post your parameters config file here?

Comment: I have just updated my question with requested information. Any help from you will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compared your JSON file with a vanilla JSON file. Seems you have done plenty of edits in it.

Especially when you:

1. Updated the Default passwords as well as added "`Value`" parameter.
2. Deleted "`SqlMessagingUser`" along with other parameters.
3. Edited the "`SqlServer`" Default value.

I would recommend:

1. If you want to override the detault password then try passing those as a
   parameter from you PS1 file OR just update the `DefaultValue` on
   both  `sitecore-XP0.json` and `xconnect-xp0.json` files for all the
   Test12345 passwords replacing with your custom password. Exactly the way it is
   suggested on the [another question which you asked](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12225/sitecore-9-installation-password-is-too-short).
2. Verify the `DefaultValue` you updated for `SqlServer` in your JSON file at line number 155.
3. Validate all the other parameters you deleted from the JSON file like `SqlMessagingUser`, `SqlMessagingPassword`, `SqlExmMasterUser`, `SqlExmMasterPassword` etc

My JSON file looks something like this after updating the Default passwords:

```
"SqlAdminUser": {
    "Type": "string",
    "DefaultValue": "sa",
    "Description": "The Sql admin user account to use when installing databases."
},
"SqlAdminPassword": {
    "Type": "string",
    "DefaultValue": "custom@1234",
    "Description": "The Sql admin password to use when installing databases."
},
"SqlCoreUser": {
    "Type": "string",
    "DefaultValue": "coreuser",
    "Description": "The user to create and use in Core connection string."
},
"SqlCorePassword": {
    "Type": "string",
    "DefaultValue": "custom@1234",
    "Description": "The Sql password for the Core connection string in Sitecore."
},
"SqlMasterUser": {
    "Type": "string",
    "DefaultValue": "masteruser",
    "Description": "The user to create and use in Master connection string."
},
"SqlMasterPassword": {
    "Type": "string",
    "DefaultValue": "custom@1234",
    "Description": "The Sql password for the Master connection string in Sitecore."
},
"SqlWebUser": {
    "Type": "string",
    "DefaultValue": "webuser",
    "Description": "The user to create and use in Web connection string."
},
"SqlWebPassword": {
    "Type": "string",
    "DefaultValue": "custom@1234",
    "Description": "The Sql password for the Web connection string in Sitecore."
},
```

Else you can have it like the way [Ed Schwehm suggested](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12225/sitecore-9-installation-password-is-too-short):

```
$SqlMarketingAutomationPassword = "Sup3rSecureS1tecore_pass!" 

$xconnectParams = @{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
    SiteName = $XConnectCollectionService
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
    SqlServer = $SqlServer
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl
    SqlMarketingAutomationPassword = $SqlMarketingAutomationPassword
}

$sitecoreParams = @{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
    SqlServer = $SqlServer
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName
    SiteName = $sitecoreSiteName
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"
    SqlMarketingAutomationPassword = $SqlMarketingAutomationPassword
}
```

Try again using a fresh JSON with minimal edits which you want to do. Good luck.

Comment: Hello @Amitabh, Thanks a lot for your reply. Honestly speaking I had so many issues starting with password that I lost track of my edits. I am sure during those edits I damaged json files. Thanks for pointing it out. I started fresh, I only edited **DefaultValue** of all passwords and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you.